# Calculates how often a value appears in c language

Tags: c, loops, numbers

how to find how often the number appears??

my code :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

 int count,same,n=7,a,max;
 max = 0;

 printf("Input Number : \n");

 for(int i=1; i<=n; i++){
   scanf("%d",a);
   if(i == 1){
    max = a;
   }
   else if(max < a){
    max = a;
   }
   else if(same < a){
     same = a;
     count++;
   }
 }
  printf("Max : %d\n",max);
  printf("Same : %d line",count);
  return0;
}
```

expected output is :

```
1
1
2
3
4
5
6

Max : 6
Same : 2 line
```

i want to count the max of the number that i input and how often the number appears if i input 2 same line of number 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems here.  First is how you call `scanf`:

```
scanf("%d",a);
```

The `%d` format specifier expects and *address* of an `int`, but you're instead passing an `int`.  Change this to:

```
scanf("%d", &a);
```

Second, you're not tracking the count of the max number correctly.  You never initialize `same`, and you don't reset the counter if the max changes.  Leave out `same` and instead check if the current number is the max:

```
   if(i == 1){
     count = 1;
     max = a;
   }
   else if(max < a){
     max = a;
     count = 1;
   }
   else if(max == a){
     count++;
   }
```

Comment: Thanks to your answer, it's very helpful to me, and the code works